# How to get obj key from FirebaseListAdapter on Item Click. FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

When subclassing FirebaseListAdapter in FirebaseUI how can one get the obj key of the item clicked?

FirebaseListAdapter has the following method which gets itemId, but returns long. But I require the object key which is in the default string format.

```
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return (long)this.mSnapshots.getItem(i).getKey().hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `FirebaseListAdapter` assumes that you always know the index/position of the item you are interacting with. Given the Android context this makes sense, since collection views are index based.

Once you know the position, you can call [`adapter.getRef(position)`](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseListAdapter.html#getRef(int)) to get the Firebase reference to the object. On that reference, you can call [`getKey()`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_getKey) to get the key. Although I recommend only doing that as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that would work. But as I need it often to create referential paths all the time, I have actually just started storing keys and id's in the object itself, and find it very convenient pattern.

Comment: We've been debating in the FirebaseUI team to store the **references** in the objects themselves, but so far have decided against it. The overhead of requiring a common base class or injector interface seemed to outweigh the advantages for the generic use-case. Of course, if you have a specific use-case the consideration can be different. I would still recommend keeping a `Firebase` ref instead of the key. Refs are lightweight and add a nice type-safe layer over just the key String.

Comment: Must be a good discussion. In my case it seems useful as I understand in many to many relational cases, you might need to create inverted indexes for each other in their own collections. so a firebase reference by default would be very helpful in this case, and probably is also frequently required in modelling many to many modelling requirements.

Comment: Also storing Firebase refs is a great suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Given Firebase version 3... Which is now that mentioned `Firebase` object to keep reference of?