# How can I get the key of the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter at populateViewHolder?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a Firebase database with a JSON structure like this:

**JSON**

```
root:{
  "users":{
    *push1*:{
      "name":"foo1",
      "email":"bar1"
    },
    *push2*:{
      "name":"foo2",
      "email":"bar2"
    }
  }
}
```

In order to populate a RecyclerView, I am using the [FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter](https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/com/firebase/ui/FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.html) class at [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-recyclerview). The problem is that I can access both "name" and "email", but in addition I need to know the *push* string (something like *-KHjGvJ7o-UBxOVGpojI*), which I don't manage to get.

**Is there any way to get the key of the reference, instead of just the value?**

What I'm trying to do is adding a new value to the JSON, leaving it like:

```
"users":{
  *push*:{
    "name":"foo",
    "email":"bar",
    "phone":"whatever"
  }
}
```

Just in case it is easier to get the reference rather than the key to generate it.

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997219/how-to-get-obj-key-from-firebaselistadapter-on-item-click-firebaseui