# AccessFirebaseRecyclerAdapter position with ItemTouchHelper

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

Currently, I have this:

```
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(); //get position which is swipe

                if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {    //if swipe left
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);    //item removed from recylcerview
                    showSnackBar(findViewById(R.id.activity_main), getString(R.string.order_cancelled), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                } else if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);    //item removed from recylcerview
                    showSnackBar(findViewById(R.id.activity_main), getString(R.string.order_completed), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                }
            }
        };
        ItemTouchHelper helper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
        helper.attachToRecyclerView(list);
```

And the `RecyclerView`'s adapter is a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` called `mAdapter`.

However, when I swipe left/right, I want to access the data in Firebase and add a value to that list (`completed: true`);

But I can't find a way to `getRef()` of the current position. What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: That should be: `mAdapter.getRef(position)`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997219/how-to-get-obj-key-from-firebaselistadapter-on-item-click-firebaseui

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen D'oh! I was trying to use `getItem(position).getRef();`! Thanks