# How to recuperate comment with the position of item recyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm a beginner in developing android

I create a news feed where you can comment on posts, to do this I use firebase as a database and I use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` and `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`

I want the user to click on the "Comment" button of the first `RecyclerView`

The second `RecyclerView` displays the comments according to the post clicked.

I have no idea how to do this, knowing that I tried by capturing the position of the post.

Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please post the code that you tried, it would make your question more genuine and more likely to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you'll need to do is record what pot the user clicked on. If you're using the Realtime Database, I recommend doing that by recording the key of the item that they clicked on. For some hints on how to do that, see:

- [Retrieving the Firebase key from onItemClick in FirebaseListAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848072/retrieving-the-firebase-key-from-onitemclick-in-firebaselistadapter)
- [How to get obj key from FirebaseListAdapter on Item Click. FirebaseUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32997219/how-to-get-obj-key-from-firebaselistadapter-on-item-click-firebaseui)

Next up, you need to pass that key to the second recycler view somehow.

If the two recycler views are in the same activity, you can use a member field to store the comment that was clicked.

If the two recycler views are in separate activities, you can store the key in Android's shared preferences. For more on this data transfer mechanism, see:

- [`SharedPreferences` in the Android reference documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)
- [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Finally, you'll need to use the key to load the comments for that specific post. This depends on your exact data structure, but I recommend starting with the [documentation on working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) or FirebaseUI, similar to what you likely already have.